# How to Increase the size of a cell text in string grid of delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-2009

i am using an string grid it has five column, i want to in crease the Text font size of 3 rd column how to do that?

```
 while not SQLQuery.Eof do
  begin

    StringGrid1.Cells[0,rowCount] := SQLQuery.FieldByName('ELEMENTNAME').AsString ;
    StringGrid1.Cells[1,rowCount] := SQLQuery.FieldByName('ELEMENTTYPE').AsString ;
    StringGrid1.Cells[2,rowCount] := SQLQuery.FieldByName('ELEMENTSTRING').AsString ;
    StringGrid1.Cells[3,rowCount] := SQLQuery.FieldByName('BLOCKNAME').AsString ;
    StringGrid1.Cells[4,rowCount] := SQLQuery.FieldByName('ATTRIBUTES').AsString;

    rowCount := rowCount + 1;
    StringGrid1.RowCount := StringGrid1.RowCount + 1;
    SQLQuery.Next;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old example, but I suspect nothing much has changed  http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=142691

Comment: thank @Energ1ser i got the solution   

    procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
          Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
        begin
          with TStringGrid(Sender) do
          begin
            if (ACol = 2) and (ARow <> 0 ) then
            begin
              Canvas.Font.Size := 15;
              Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 2, Cells[ACol, ARow]);
            end;
           end;
        end;